# Remove character from multiple lists

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
PB = ['1','2','3', '10']
LB = ['12', '5', '21']
```

I would like to remove everything with a '1' from the lists. I can remove one item at a time with:

```
for notAWinner in [PB, LB]:
    notAWinner.remove('1')
```

The remove does not work for multiple arguments. How would I remove 1, 10, 12 & 21 with one command?

Comment: notAWinner is the variable name that I was using in my code.

Comment: `your_list_without_garbage = [i for i in your_list if not i in [1,10,12,21]]`

Comment: I would type that as is? This will work on multiple lists at one time?

Comment: Is there a way to search for if a 1 is in the item, and if so remove it?

Comment: Yes. if you want to loop over multiple list, you would just expand that list comprehension. `[[i for i in your_list if not i in [1,10,12,21]] for your_list in [PB, LB]]`, this will generate a list of list that has all been stripped of these numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a pseudo code(y) solution.

```
results = []

for i in PB + LB:
  if '1' not in i:
    results.append(i)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
no_ones = [i for i in PB + LB if '1' not in i]
```

You can replace the `PB + LB` part of the code with any list that you want.
It will return all items without 1's

```
print(no_ones)
```

Here is a function for it, just pass in whatever list you want and it will return it without the 1's

```
def remove_ones(l):
    return [i for i in l if '1' not in i]
```

Comment: I copy and pasted it as is and it did not remove the items with a 1 in it.

Comment: you have to print no_ones. It is a new list without the ones

Answer (score 1):

You can `filter` out the unwanted items:

```
PB = list(filter(lambda x: '1' not in x, PB))
LB = list(filter(lambda x: '1' not in x, LB))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your `PB` and `LB` to refer to a new list, it will be easy, by using filter+lambda or list-comprehension

```
PB = list(filter(lambda s: '1' not in s, PB))   #filter

LB = [s for s in LB if '1' not in s]  # List comprehension
```

However, if you need to remove it in-place in the existing list, it seems a bit tricky.  One way is the replace the content of existing list with slicing syntax:

```
# similar to what you are doing in your question
for my_list in (PB, LB):
    # my_list  = [s for s in my_list if '1' not in s]  
    # The above will not affect the original PB and LB

    my_list[:] = [s for s in my_list if '1' not in s]
    # The above will replace the content of original PB and LB
```

Answer (score 0):

Two lines is best I can do:

```
PB = ['1','2','3', '10']
LB = ['12', '5', '21']
notAWinner = ['1', '10', '12', '21']

for ls in LB, PB:
    [i if i not in notAWinner else ls.remove(i) for i in ls.copy()]
```